# Set sprout video in iframe equals to 100%, height

Tags: html, css, iframe

This is my scenario I have embed a sprout video in an iframe, I have set the parent div to, 254px width and 452px height.

And my iframe, I have set it to 100% width and 100% height. My Iframe is stretching 100% but my video didn't.

How do I stretch the video equals to 100%? Any suggestion would be greatly appriciated.

Below is my code:

--html

```
<div class="slide">
      <iframe src="//videos.sproutvideo.com/embed/119ed9b71910edcb98/af3ed4454a4a14d6" frameborder="0" referrerpolicy="no-referrer-when-downgrade"></iframe>
</div>
```

--css

```
.slide{
  position: relative;
  width: 254px;
  height: 452px;
{
iframe{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: HTML will not automatically stretch a video to the sizes you wish, if you set with 100% width and height from the parent element. Maybe try it with inherit: iframe{
  position: absolute;
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
}

Comment: That's really not how those iframe embeds for videos usually work. Their priority is showing the _full_ video, not to cut parts of it off. So if you make your iframe higher than what the actual video aspect ratio would require at the current width, you will get black bars added on top and bottom, not get your video "cut". You would have to make your iframe so wide, that at the current height it still has the same aspect ratio as the video itself (which you would need to know beforehand), and then you'd need to hide the excess parts of the iframe.

Comment: @CBroe I just want to set the video to 254px width and 452height, how do i achieve this? I am not too familliar with how aspect ratios work

Comment: The aspect ratio of your video there appears to be 16:9, so if you want it 452 pixels high, then the iframe width needs to be 452 / 9 * 16, so about 804px. And that excess width of the iframe you will have to cut then (by centering it inside an element with 254px width, that cuts overflow off.)

Comment: how did you measure the aspect ratio sir? @CBroe

Comment: I didn't, I guessed it. 16:9 is probably still the most common format.

Answer (score 0):

HTML will not automatically stretch a video to the sizes you wish, if you set with 100% width and height from the parent element. Maybe try it with inherit:

```
iframe{
  position: absolute;
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
}
```

Also, you are inheriting propertes from your css class "sproutvideo-player". If this class is not self-programmed, try to get information about this class and then override the properties you want to change via css.

Comment: I have remove the class, Im not using it. Iframe has already inherited the parent width and height. My problem is the video inside it, not stretching!

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this but you'll loose some of your controls

```
<div class='contents'>
    <div class="slide">
        <iframe src="//videos.sproutvideo.com/embed/119ed9b71910edcb98/af3ed4454a4a14d6" frameborder="0" referrerpolicy="no-referrer-when-downgrade"></iframe>
    </div>
</div>


.contents {
    position: relative;
    width: 254px;
    height: 452px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.slide{
    position: relative;
    aspect-ratio: 16 / 9;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}

iframe{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    aspect-ratio: 16 / 9;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```